# Codeigniter - Sparks to composer, activerecord issues now

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, phpactiverecord

So I have just gone through a update going from CI 2.0.4 to 3.1.4 and ran into the issue with Sparks now being redundant I've had to move onto composer to get php active record working..

however I have had autoloading issues/ Solved by including the model directly into the controller ie: `require_once(APPPATH.'models/User.php');`

But now im getting the following error..

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: ActiveRecord\DatabaseException
>
> Message: Empty connection string
>
> Filename: /var/www/html/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php
>
> Line Number: 105

btw to load the composer autoload I've put: `config['composer_autoload'] = '../vendor/autoload.php';` as the vendor directory sits outside the application folder in its parents folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the vendor directory to your public_html/www and try

```
config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
```